# Jquery and .parent()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following markup and JS, why does the first statement work and the seond not?

**jQuery**

```js
$('.selector').change(function () {
  // does work
  $(this).parent(".controls").after( "<div class=\"control-group\">Test</div>" );

  // doesn't work
  $(this).parent(".control-group").after( "<div class=\"control-group\">Test</div>" );
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="description">Section Type</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select class="selector">
      // options
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `this` is a dom element - i should have been more clear this is inside a llamda function from a .change Event

Comment: I don't see the change event function... so I can't answer.

Comment: Which DOM element fires the change event?. And where is it included in the html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use:

- [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), which gives you only the first element matching that selector (starting at the currently selected element), or
- [**.parents()**](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to give you all the parents matching that selector (starting at the currently selected element's parent).

The [**.parent()**](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method *only travels a single level up the DOM tree*.

Answer (score 1):

BAH! I should have RTFM!

> The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the
>   latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree